How to edit OneDrive text file from vscode?
I have one folder in onedrive and I wonder if I can use VS Code to edit the remote files ?
I have notes and a couple of node scripts there. I am looking for some kind of file-sync service of sorts that stores what I have locally into this specific folder.
Onedrive app won't do the trick because I want to sync only 1 folder from my onedrive folder and not everything there.

Didn't try myself but couldn't you simply share that one folder with yourself and dock that to your shared OneDrive folders?

My idea is not to sync the entire onedrive in my machine. I just want to share 1 folder from my one-drive , or sync it for security reason and not the entire drive
